# How do get correct instance name on Multi instance cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, dmv

Just a quick question and somehow unable to figure it out.

We have a Active Active cluster or should i say Multi instance cluster as below. node A and B are part of same window cluster

> Node A --> Serv1\SQLINSt1
>
> Node B --> Serv2\SQLINSt2

How can i show the info that node A at a time host instance Serv1\SQLINSt1 and node B other instance Serv2\SQLINSt2 because when i use dmv `sys.dm_os_cluster nodes` and add `SERVERPROPERTY ('instancename')` it gives same SQL instance for both the nodes

Also will it be possible to show when both the instances come on says node A while node B host no instance?

Much appreciated thanks

Comment: If you have 2 different instances, then SERVERPROPERTY ('instancename') should not return the same value for both (unless you run your query on the same instance twice).
How do you connect to the instance ? (do you specify the instance name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each instance, run:

```
SELECT
  ServerAndInstanceName = @@SERVERNAME, 
  UnderlyingServerName  = SERVERPROPERTY(N'ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS');
```

If they both show the same `UnderlyingServerName` then they're both on the same node.